# How to replace an element in a mongodb list using the C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Let's assume a document like this:

```
public class Element
{
    public string _id;
    public string Name;
}

public class Test
{
    public string _id;
    public List<Element> Elements;

    public Test()
    {
        Elements = new List<Element>();
    }
}
```

If I have a document of type Test, I can add elements to the list with *push* in the update:

```
Update.Push(_ => _.Elements, e);
```

or, remove a specific element from the list using *PullFilter*:

```
Update.PullFilter<Element>(_ => _.Elements, f => f._id == "...");
```

but how can I replace an element with a specific _id field?

I don't want to do a Pull / Push, I would like to do it in on step so that the update is either done, or not.

ideally, I'd like something like

```
Update(_ => _.Elements.Id == "...", myNewElement)
```

Edit:

this is a dup of [Replace Embedded Document using Mongo C# 2.0 driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141646/replace-embedded-document-using-mongo-c-sharp-2-0-driver)

I'm not sure if we should close this one, or keep it as a reference for the other one, which I couldn't find that easily due to different keywords.

Comment: You create Filter for it and then pass to update.

Comment: you mean using LinQ? something like Elements.Where(_ => _.Id == ...) ?

Comment: what syntax would that take? because I need to make a query to identify the document and then add to it another one to identify the element in the list.

Comment: Update.Set("field name", element). Then on update you pass filter with it.

Comment: Are you using latest driver?

Comment: yes, latest driver; the field in question is a list, I don't want to replace the list, I want to replace a specific element in that list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace Embedded Document using Mongo C# 2.0 driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141646/replace-embedded-document-using-mongo-c-sharp-2-0-driver)

Comment: The answer in above link is correct.